# How to compute distance between my original and supplied point in Java

Tags: java, point

```
public class Point {

private double X, Y;


  public Point() {
    setPoint(0.0,0.0);
  }

   public Point (double X, double Y) {
      setPoint(X,Y);
   }

  public void setPoint(double X, double Y) {
    this.X = X;
    this.Y = Y;
  }
  public double getX() {

    return this.X;
  }
  public double getY() {

    return this.Y;
  }

 /**
     * Compute the distance of this Point to the supplied Point x.
     *
     * @param x  Point from which the distance should be measured.
     * @return   The distance between x and this instance
     */
    public double distance(Point x) {


    double d= Math.pow(this.X-X,2)+Math.pow(this.Y-Y,2);
    return Math.sqrt(d); 
}
```

I'm trying to compute the distance of my "original point" and my supplied point x. I'm not exactly sure if i'm doing this right. My main concern is:

> How do I refer to the coordinates of my original point and the supplied point? The maths here is basic, so I'm confident with that.

Any help is appreciated. PS I'm new to Java.

So also I was thinking of assigning my point the value within the function:

```java
public double distance(Point x) {

    Point x = new Point(X,Y);
    double d= Math.pow(this.X-x.X,2)+Math.pow(this.Y-x.Y,2);
    return Math.sqrt(d); 
}
```

Would this be fine?

Comment: Why have `Point x = new Point(X,Y);` at all? You lose the data you got as a parameter and then end up comparing one point to itself. Just remove that line and isn't the code fine then?

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen okay, that makes sense. Thanks:)

Comment: @SergeBallesta Okay, but why exactly am I overwriting the point here? Aren't i'm just assigning a value to the point ```x```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't use in the parameter.

```
public double distance(Point other) {

        double d = Math.pow(other.getX()- getX(), 2) + Math.pow(other.getY() - getY(), 2);

        return Math.sqrt(d); 
}
```

Comment: This is not the issue here.

Comment: Never said it was not not a valid answer either ;-) . My remark is just to say that `Math.power` is more expensive that a simple product. For integral type accuracy should be considered, but not for floating point ones.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But why exactly do we have to use the getX() method?

Comment: @user6969 Because the get accessor may have a logic.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a class like below:

```
public class Point {
    private double x;
    private double y;

    ...constructors and methods omitted
}
```

To calculate distance between your point and another one you can use the java standard method [Math.hypot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#hypot-double-double-) like below:

```
public double distance(Point other) {
   return Math.hypot(this.x - other.x, this.y - other.y);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**Math.sqrt((x1-x2)(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)(y1-y2))**